# What is the correct notation for flipping $a$ and $b$ values in a complex?

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

I'm currently doing some experiments on fractals and in one of my equation I need to flip the real and imaginary components of a complex number, such as :

$$
z = a + bi
$$

Becomes :

$$
z = b + ai
$$

What would be the correct mathematical term or notation for this ? `flip` ?

Comment: I don't think there is one? Note however that this is $-\overline{iz}$ (that's a complex conjugate)

Comment: Equivalently to @coolydudey60's suggestion, this is $(\mathrm i\cdot\bar z)$.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks. One of you should post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the comments, if $$z = a +  bi$$ then $$i\cdot\bar z = b+ai$$ where $\bar z$ is the conjugate of $z$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know such notation, but note that in general, 
$$(a+bi)\times \left(\frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}i\right)=b+ai$$
where $(a,b)\not=(0,0).$

Answer (score 1):

If you represent the complex no. as:
$$z=a+bi=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{i\arctan(b/a)}$$

Then the flipped number can be written as:

$$z'=b+ai=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{i\cdot(\pi/2-arctan(b/a))}$$